# Doctrine migrations add new column uniquie

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

I want add a new column with `uniquie=true` but every time get `duplicate values ''` , this column i want to be `not null`. How can i construct a migration to do that, i was try many ways but i read only if have my update query in `function up` this query will be loaded. but in `function postUp` i set my unique fields vales.

This i was trying but not working:

```
public function postUp(Schema $schema){
    $users = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->findAll();
    foreach($users as $user){
        $user->setAffiliatesToken(uniqid().str_replace(' ','',str_replace('.','',microtime())));
    }
    $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E952C22EB5 ON users (affiliates_token)');
    $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_1483A5E99F12C49A ON users (affiliate_id)');
    $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->flush();
}
```

Comment: You have to execute the `flush()` *before* the migration queries. Otherwise the changes to the tokens will only be in Doctrine’s memory and not in the database itself, which will then complain about (still) duplicate values.

Comment: but i used flush with doctrine managere before that, but in documentation say all update query should be in `up` function and this is problem, this update my fields but not add uniquie index after flush.